# Filter list of apps on SD card / internal

Tags: android

**Update** I must target Android 2.1.

I am trying to find out how to list apps programatically, filtered by being on the SD card or internal storage.

I'm not certain how to even approach this. Should I first detect the SD card mount point and see if an app data directory is on it? For example

```
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
  Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);     
  List<ResolveInfo> intents = m_pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
  File baseSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

  int count = intents.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    String baseApp = intents.get(i).activityInfo.applicationInfo.dataDir;
    if (baseApp.startsWith(baseSD.getAbsolutePath()) {
      // This is on the SD card, do whatever with the app details
    }
    else {
      // This is on internal storage
    }
  }
}
```

Seems very low-brow, there must be a more proper way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code for checking where an app is installed:

```
PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo("packageName", 0);

if ((pi.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == 0)
   ; // stored on internal storage
else 
   ; // stored on sd
```

Be careful because FLAG_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is available starting from Android API 8.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and it does actually answer my initial question, however I do need to target 2.1. So far all examples I can find use the directory to match. I'll update my question.

Comment: After thinking about this, this part of my app doesn't make sense unless they are using 2.2 so this works fine.

Comment: For me it is the same, I have part of my app that can be used starting from android 2.2. Anyway cheer up because 85% of the android version out there are 2.2 and up. http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html